# Symfony2: setFlash with basic html in the message

Tags: symfony, session

I'm trying to set a flash message for my template that includes very basic anchor to another page in the app.

Using the standard method apparently won't do the job:

```
$this->get('session')
     ->setFlash('message', 'Some <a href="#">link</a>');
```

I found some suggestions in Symfony's 2.0 forums, but they don't work either:

```
$this->get('session')
     ->setFlash('message', sprtintf('Some %s', '<a href="#">link</a>'));

$this->get('session')
     ->setFlash('message', sprtintf('Some %s', link_to('routeHere', 'link')));
```

**Edit**

In my template I render all flashes in the most common way:

```
{% for label, flash in app.session.getFlashes() %}
    <div class="message {{ label }}">
        {{ flash }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you don't see the flash messages?

Comment: @Leggendario I do see them, but with the raw html in them. Like the entities are not encoded but just printed - tags, quotes and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of `{{ flash }}` is escaped by Twig automatically. You need to use the [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) filter like

```
{{ flash|raw }}
```

Comment: Dang, I knew it was something simple. Thanks a bunch !! Works like a charm.